# convex concave sign in tkz-tab

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, symbols

I'm a newby with both `tkz-tab` and `tikz`. I'd like to use `tkz-tab` to present the analysis of a function.

Is there a way to draw symbols for convex and concave that span over the whole diagram's cell, in the way the arrow are drawn ?

Up to now I've tried to use cup and cap symbols, but the result is not suitable. I would like to have something like a portion of a parabola.

Here is a mwe :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amsmath,fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=2,espcl=1]{
    $x$         /1,
    $\sin(x)$   /1
}% 
{
    $-\pi$, $0$ , $\pi$ 
}%
\tkzTabLine{  , {\Huge \smile} , t , \frown , }
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a link to a page showing the symbols you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide a link right now, but the symbols may look like `\smile` and `\frown` but span across the cell.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *diagram's cell*; I've never used `tkz-tab` myself. Could you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? That usually helps in getting a quick and satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 4):

One simple possibility, using `\draw` and some of the predefined nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=2,espcl=1]{
    $x$         /1,
    $\sin(x)$   /1
}% 
{
    $-\pi$, $0$ , $\pi$ 
}%
\tkzTabLine{  , , t , , }
\draw[cyan,shorten >= 7pt,shorten <= 7pt] 
  ( $(T11)!0.2!(T12)$ ) to[out=-50,in=230,looseness=1.4] ( $(N21)!0.2!(N22)$ );
\draw[cyan,yscale=-1,shorten >= 7pt,shorten <= 7pt] 
  ( $(N22)!0.1!(N21)$ ) to[out=-50,in=230,looseness=1.4] ( $(T22)!0.1!(T21)$ );
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried it with slightly wider columns (espcl=2): the curve are crossing the table's borders. Is there a way to adjust automatically the looseness ? Further idea: is there a way to create commands, for instance `\convexe` and `\concave` that do the drawings automatically where it is typed ? In that case, the nodes used for the drawing should be choosen relatively to the place the command is typed.

Comment: @svannay Since TikZ is being used, surely there's a way, but that would imply going into the code of the package, and I don't have time to do so. Perhaps the package author (who is one of the regulars here) will read your question and provide a more automatic solution.